# Getting Memory Error: while plotting large values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

My X axis range is 0 to 4294967296( which is 2^32), i.e, i want to plot upto 4294967296 in X axis in matplotlib. But  I am getting error that "Memory Error".

How to avoid memory Error?

```html
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3161, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1819, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1383, in plot
    self.add_line(line)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1703, in add_line
    self._update_line_limits(line)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1725, in _update_line_limits
    path = line.get_path()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 938, in get_path
    self.recache()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 647, in recache
    self._xy = np.empty((len(x), 2), dtype=np.float_)
MemoryError
```

```html
plt.xlim(0,4294967295)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.xlabel("Sequence number")
plt.ylabel("Cumulative_distribution")
plt.plot(x,y,linewidth=3,color="blue")
plt.savefig('seqnum_plot.eps', format='eps')
plt.show()
```

Comment: When reporting about an error, you need to include the [mcve] of the code that produces the error, as well as a full error traceback.

Comment: In response to your edit - you need to give some sample data that also reproduces the problem. Just how much data are you trying to plot??

Comment: My data values are, x=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...... 4294967295]                                        y= [0  0.0673  0.673  0.078  0.99.....1]                                                              i.e, x is ranging from 0 to 4294967295                                                                  and y is ranging from 0 to 1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to plot a very large number of sample points. There are a number of issues with that.

For a start, how many pixels does your screen have? How much of that data can you expect to be visible on a plotted graph? Much less than 2^32 worth.

The other issue is one of memory. Matplotlib is just not designed to deal with plotting datasets that may not fit on the physical memory of the machine you're running it on. So, what's the solution?

Downsampling.

How this is implemented will depend on what type of function your data represents. Is it monotonically decreasing/increasing? How quickly does the data fluctuate? For a sense of the issues in accurately representing time series data for human interpretation, have a quick read of [this](http://skemman.is/stream/get/1946/15343/37285/3/SS_MSthesis.pdf) Master's thesis (**"Downsampling time series for visual representation"** by Sveinn Steinarsson).

If your y data represents a cumulative distribution (presume it will be slow to fluctuate and monotonically increasing), you could simply sample every *n*th element as so:

```
step_size = 2**20
x = x_old[::step_size]
y = y_old[::step_size]
```

Note that `y_old` and `x_old` need to be Numpy arrays for this slicing to work.

Comment: Thanks for your stuff. I tried with slicing as you said. But it was stopping and giving "Killed" response. How to solve it?

Comment: Can you reduce your sampling rate some other way? Where are you getting the data from?

Comment: I am getting data from Text file.

Comment: Can you put the relevant code up? We're going to go back and forth forever otherwise. I suspect you might need to selectively read in lines of data (say, every 100,000 lines?) to avoid your out of memory issues. That text file must be huge...

Comment: Yes, you are right, my text file is some 18MB. May I know, how to get  some 1,00,000 lines at a time from text file, (which is having some 2^32 lines) by using "With open" function?

Comment: Something's not adding up. A text file containing 2^32 lines of data should be at least 4GB. Most likely much, much more, depending how the data is encoded. Just 2^32 lines of `\n` would be 4GB worth. 18MB is nothing at all. Now before we go any further, can you PLEASE post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as asked previously. People here should be able to take your code and run it to reproduce the error. We're all poking around in the dark without it.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. I am not able to add code, it was raising some space problems. I could have add otherwise.

Comment: Go and edit your original question, and add the relevant code. If you can't (or won't) do that, then I can't help you without descending into endless comments.